# Most efficient way to check if sublist is present in list, ignoring the last element

Tags: python, list, performance, search

I have a list that's structured like this:

```py
[
    [1, 2, 'A'],
    [3, 4, 'B'],
    [5, 6, 'C'],
    ...
]
```

I want to check if there exists a list inside this list, such that the *first two* elements are some numbers `m` and `n`, and ignore the last string element.

I know that this is the most straightforward way to do it:

```py
def contains_first_two(m : int, n : int, search : list) -> bool:
    
    for el in search:
        if el[0] == m and el[1] == n:
            return True
    
    return False
```

but I'm wondering if there's a faster solution I haven't thought of.

Comment: Not necessarily faster, but it's more *concise* to write using `any`: `any(el[0] == m and el[1] == n for el in search)`.

Comment: does m and n order matter ? like m should be first element and n should be second ?

Comment: consider using other types of structure, for example `set`, `ordereddict` if order matters, etc.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος the lists are sorted by their third element, and the first element need not always be less than the second.

Comment: In that case, binary search will likely be useless here. So your solution is probably extremely efficient, if not the most efficient.

Comment: I would do: `any(i==m and j==n for i,j,*the_rest in search)`

Comment: Is the real use case also just simple lists of length 3?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe iterating through the whole list and performing `any`?

```py
def contains_first_two(m: int, n: int, search: list) -> bool:
    return any((el[0] == m and el[1] == n) for el in search)
```

When executed:

```
my_list = [
    [1, 2, 'A'],
    [3, 4, 'B'],
    [5, 6, 'C']
]

result = contains_first_two(3, 4, my_list)
print(result)  # Output: True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class search:
    def __init__(self, m, n):
        self.m, self.n = m, n
    def __call__(self, data: list) -> bool:
        match data:
            case [self.m, self.n, _]:
                return True
            case _:
                return False

se = search(3, 4)
any(se(x) for x in lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?tuple#tuple), [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)
and [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) for more pythonic solution. It is slower than `any`-based solution if you have to perform a small number of lookups (because it has to convert the *entire* list before doing the first lookup). But it is faster for a large number of lookups due to efficiency of sets.

```
lst = [
    [1, 2, 'A'],
    [3, 4, 'B'],
    [5, 6, 'C'],
]

set_for_lookup = {tuple(sublist[0:-1])for sublist in lst}

contains_first_two = (3, 4) in set_for_lookup
print(contains_first_two)

contains_first_two = (3, 0) in set_for_lookup
print(contains_first_two)
```

Comment: This is probably *slower*, as you have to build the entire set of truncated sublists first before you can start looking for (3, 4). The OP's can stop iterating immediately on a match.

Comment: It's only faster for a large number of lookups if you *save* the set to reuse.